# Need LINQ equivalent of SQL query

Tags: sql, linq

I need linq equivalent of below sql query. Linq is returing more records than the sql query. Can some one please help me fix the linq.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.productname, u.areaonename,u.areatwoname, u.areathreename,u.areafourname, u.areafivename,a.agentproductid,tt.triptypename
 FROM Underwriter AS u 
 INNER JOIN Rateset AS r ON u.Underwriterid = r.underwriterid
 INNER JOIN  BaseProduct b ON b.ratesetid = r.ratesetid
 INNER JOIN AgentProduct a ON a.baseproductid = b.baseproductid
 INNER JOIN AgentBranding ab ON a.agentproductid in( ab.productoneid,  ab.producttwoid, 
 ab.productthreeid, ab.productfourid,ab.productfiveid)
 INNER JOIN Agent ag ON ag.defaultagentbrandingid = ab.agentbrandingid
 INNER JOIN triptypelink tl on tl.linkid in(  a.agentproductid, a.agentproductid, 
 a.agentproductid,a.agentproductid, a.agentproductid)
 INNER JOIN triptype tt on tl.triptypeid = tt.triptypeid
 WHERE ag.agentid = 1234
```

Here is what I've tried

`

```
 (from un in db.Underwriters
                               join r in db.Ratesets on un.UnderwriterId equals r.UnderwriterId
                               join bs in db.BaseProducts on r.RatesetId equals bs.RatesetId
                               join ap in db.AgentProducts on bs.BaseProductId equals 
                                ap.BaseProductId
                               from ag in db.AgentBrandings.Where(x => ap.AgentProductId == 
                             x.ProductOneId || ap.AgentProductId == x.ProductTwoId ||
                             ap.AgentProductId == x.ProductThreeId || ap.AgentProductId == 
                                x.ProductFourId || ap.AgentProductId == x.ProductFiveId)
                               join at in db.Agents on ag.AgentId equals at.AgentId 
                               from ttl in db.TripTypeLinks where  where (ag.ProductOneId == 
                                ttl.LinkId || ag.ProductTwoId == ttl.LinkId ||
                                ag.ProductThreeId == ttl.LinkId || ag.ProductFourId == ttl.LinkId || 
                                ag.ProductFiveId == ttl.LinkId)
                               join tt in db.TripTypes on ttl.TripTypeId equals tt.TripTypeId 
                               where at.AgentId.Equals(agentId) 
                               select new AgentModel
                               {
                                   AreaOne = un.AreaOneName,
                                   AreaTwo = un.AreaTwoName,
                                   AreaThree = un.AreaThreeName,
                                   AreaFour = un.AreaFourName,
                                   AreaFive = un.AreaFiveName,
                                   ProductId = ap.AgentProductId,
                                   ProductName = ap.ProductName,
                                   TripTypeName = tt.TripTypeName,
                                   TripTypeCode = tt.TripTypeCode,
                                   TripTypeId = tt.TripTypeId
                               }
                                    )
                                  .Distinct().ToListAsync<AgentModel>();`
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you define the joins manually? Are they not in your data model already? Given that the data model has them, there is no need to define any of the join conditions If not - that is a fundamental flaw.

Comment: Please show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?). And, what exactly needs fixing?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend replacing the joins with simple from statements. joins usually don't perform good with a remote data source.

So your query would look something like this:

```
from un in db.Underwriters
from r in db.Ratesets 
from bs in db.BaseProducts
from ap in db.AgentProducts
from ag in db.AgentBrandings
from at in db.Agents 
from ttl in db.TripTypeLinks
from tt in db.TripTypes
where un.UnderwriterId == r.UnderwriterId
where r.RatesetId == bs.RatesetId
where bs.BaseProductId == ap.BaseProductId
Where ap.AgentProductId == x.ProductOneId 
      || ap.AgentProductId == x.ProductTwoId 
      || ap.AgentProductId == x.ProductThreeId 
      || ap.AgentProductId == x.ProductFourId 
      || ap.AgentProductId == x.ProductFiveId
where ag.AgentId equals at.AgentId 
where ag.ProductOneId == ttl.LinkId 
      || ag.ProductTwoId == ttl.LinkId 
      || ag.ProductThreeId == ttl.LinkId 
      || ag.ProductFourId == ttl.LinkId 
      || ag.ProductFiveId == ttl.LinkId
where ttl.TripTypeId == tt.TripTypeId 
where at.AgentId.Equals(agentId) 
select new AgentModel
       {
          AreaOne = un.AreaOneName,
          AreaTwo = un.AreaTwoName,
          AreaThree = un.AreaThreeName,
          AreaFour = un.AreaFourName,
          AreaFive = un.AreaFiveName,
          ProductId = ap.AgentProductId,
          ProductName = ap.ProductName,
          TripTypeName = tt.TripTypeName,
          TripTypeCode = tt.TripTypeCode,
          TripTypeId = tt.TripTypeId
         }
                                    )
                                  .Distinct().ToListAsync<AgentModel>();
```

I am not sure if it will work as I dont know how the data is structured, but it's worth a try!

and if you are still not getting the required results, then it might be a good idea to break the query down in parts and get the required result first (because these are a lottttt of joins in a single query), and then try to patch it up together.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No. Removing joins is a very bad idea. The statement is translated into SQL and relational databases have all kinds of optimizations for join statements. There's no backing for your statement *joins usually don't perform good with a remote data source*.